# What newline to use when writing to stdout on windows

Tags: python, windows, newline, stdout, stderr

If I make a Python script with

```py
import sys

sys.stdout('a\nb\nc')
```

and then run it, I get

```
$ python check_stdout.py
a
b
c
```

If I change it to

```py
import sys

sys.stdout('a\r\nb\r\nc')
```

then I still get

````
```console
$ python check_stdout.py
a
b
c
````

So is it OK to use `\n` as a line separator when writing to stdout or stderr on Windows?

Comment: When you output to console, it does not matter because windows console interprets \n as newline. When you output to a file in "non-binary" mode, if you use python3 \n will be converted to environment specific newline character.

Comment: OK. So if I'm making a Python command-line tool and want to output a message which spans multiple lines, I'm OK to write e.g. `sys.stderr('a\nb\nc')` so it'll work across platforms?

Comment: If you use python 3, stdout and stderr is opened in text mode (I couldn't find where this is stated in the docs but they are most likely opened in text mode) and interpreter will handle newline conversions.

Comment: Yup, Python3.6+. Cool, thanks!

Comment: Something to consider -- will you always be on windows or will this script ever run on linux?

Comment: it'lll run on both

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` or `\r\n` on Windows without a problem. However, if you are writing to stderr and stdout it's best practice to match the OS definitions of newlines so it will be better to use `\r\n`